# Mixing QT and Mathematica

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, wolfram-mathematica, glib

I have a CMake project where I have written a C++ library "mathematica++" that abstracts mathematica's `WSTP` calls and transports C++ objects as mathematica objects. For this I use [`Mathematica CMake Module`](https://github.com/sakra/FindMathematica) available on github.

I have another command line subproject that uses the library `mathematica++` as a shared library and everything works fine.

I have another GUI project using QT5 that also links with `mathematica++` that doesn't start. However a QT5 based Hello world application compiles and runs fine. Even if I just remove the mathematica++ dependency it starts to work. When QT5 and mathematica is both linked I get the following error

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".
>
> Available platform plugins are: custom-wayland, eglfs, linuxfb,
>   minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, wayland-egl, wayland,
>   wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Aborted (core
>   dumped)

If I use QT4 instead of QT5 I get a different error

> QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the
>   proper libraries.

However both QT4 and QT5 based applications are running fine. Even the commandline sub project which uses mathematica libraries is also running fine. I don't know whether Mathametica libraries have any gtk/glib2 dependencies that are conflicting with QT's gtk/glib2 dependencies. But as its not a GUI library I don't know why would it have gtk/glib2 dependencies. I suspect that mathematica and QT are refering to two different versions of gtk/glib2 libraries.

Following are the dependencies of the GUI application when compiled with mathematica dependencies

```
$ ldd schedulerqt
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcff782000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f9898424000)
    libmathematica++.so => /home/sensiaas/projects/senschedule/build/mathematica++/libmathematica++.so (0x00007f9898170000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f9897ccd000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f9897843000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.60.0 => /lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f989762b000)
    libboost_system.so.1.60.0 => /lib64/libboost_system.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f9897427000)
    libWSTP64i4.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libWSTP64i4.so (0x00007f9896fd5000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9896c4d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9896a2f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9896827000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9896621000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f989641c000)
    libML64i4.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i4.so (0x00007f98961e8000)
    libWolframRTL.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libWolframRTL.so (0x00007f9895ee2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9895bd9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f98959c2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f98955fa000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f9895389000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f9895122000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9894f0a000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f9894cd7000)
    libicui18n.so.57 => /lib64/libicui18n.so.57 (0x00007f989485d000)
    libicuuc.so.57 => /lib64/libicuuc.so.57 (0x00007f98944b4000)
    libicudata.so.57 => /lib64/libicudata.so.57 (0x00007f9892a37000)
    libpcre16.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre16.so.0 (0x00007f98927ce000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f98925cd000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9892270000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib64/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f98921e5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558688c3a000)
    libmkl_def.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_def.so (0x00007f9890517000)
    libmkl_intel_ilp64.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.so (0x00007f988fbb5000)
    libmkl_core.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_core.so (0x00007f988e10e000)
    libmkl_intel_thread.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_intel_thread.so (0x00007f988c700000)
    libiomp5.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libiomp5.so (0x00007f988c35d000)
    libippcc.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippcc.so (0x00007f988c142000)
    libippcv.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippcv.so (0x00007f988bf1f000)
    libippi.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippi.so (0x00007f988bc7c000)
    libipps.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libipps.so (0x00007f988ba36000)
    libippvm.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippvm.so (0x00007f988b820000)
    libippcore.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippcore.so (0x00007f988b614000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f988b3e8000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f988b1e5000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f988afe2000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f988addb000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /lib64/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f988abd8000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /lib64/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f988a9a9000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f988a780000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f988a56e000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f988a36b000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f988a165000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f9889f63000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f9889c24000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f98899fa000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f98897df000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f98895da000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f98893d4000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f98891c3000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f9888f2f000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9888d14000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f9888b0f000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f98888e9000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib64/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f98886d5000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib64/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f98883ef000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f98881d9000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f9887fd5000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f9887d62000)
```

Following are the dependencies of the command line tool

```
$ ldd scheduler
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc6ff02000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.60.0 => /lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f1824b96000)
    libboost_system.so.1.60.0 => /lib64/libboost_system.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f1824992000)
    libmathematica++.so => /home/sensiaas/projects/senschedule/build/mathematica++/libmathematica++.so (0x00007f18246de000)
    libWSTP64i4.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTP/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libWSTP64i4.so (0x00007f182428a000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1823f02000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1823ce4000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1823adc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f18238d8000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f18236d3000)
    libML64i4.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i4.so (0x00007f182349d000)
    libWolframRTL.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libWolframRTL.so (0x00007f1823197000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1822e8e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1822c77000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f18228b1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000561db3517000)
    libmkl_def.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_def.so (0x00007f1820be3000)
    libmkl_intel_ilp64.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.so (0x00007f1820281000)
    libmkl_core.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_core.so (0x00007f181e7da000)
    libmkl_intel_thread.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libmkl_intel_thread.so (0x00007f181cdcc000)
    libiomp5.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libiomp5.so (0x00007f181ca29000)
    libippcc.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippcc.so (0x00007f181c810000)
    libippcv.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippcv.so (0x00007f181c5eb000)
    libippi.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippi.so (0x00007f181c348000)
    libipps.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libipps.so (0x00007f181c102000)
    libippvm.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippvm.so (0x00007f181beec000)
    libippcore.so => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libippcore.so (0x00007f181bce0000)
```

Comment: What are the dependencies of your command line tool which is linked with mathematica++? You could consider linking dependencies statically to a self-contained shared library and loading this at runtime from your qt app

Comment: added dependencies of the command line app (scheduler)

Comment: probably `SET(Mathematica_USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES ON)` worked

Comment: yes if my library mathematica++ links to mathematica's static libraries it works. However Now I see the surprisingly expected thing. a ghost windows of mathematica 11.1 appears when I do some mathematica operation through the gui application. Probably thats why mathematica's library have gtk dependency